# Star schema in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, star-schema

I have a star-schema architectured database that I want to represent in SQLAlchemy. Now I have the problem on how this can be done in the best possible way. Right now I have a lot of properties with custom join conditions, because the data is stored in different tables.
It would be nice if it would be possible to re-use the dimensions for different fact tablesw but I haven't figured out how that can be done nicely.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A typical fact table in a star schema contains foreign key references to all dimension tables, so usually there wouldn't be any need for custom join conditions - they are determined automatically from foreign key references.

For example a star schema with two fact tables would look like:

```
Base = declarative_meta()

class Store(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'store'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(50), nullable=False)

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(50), nullable=False)

class FactOne(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_fact_one'

    store_id = Column('store_id', Integer, ForeignKey('store.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_id = Column('product_id', Integer, ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True)
    units_sold = Column('units_sold', Integer, nullable=False)

    store = relation(Store)
    product = relation(Product)

class FactTwo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_fact_two'

    store_id = Column('store_id', Integer, ForeignKey('store.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_id = Column('product_id', Integer, ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True)
    units_sold = Column('units_sold', Integer, nullable=False)

    store = relation(Store)
    product = relation(Product)
```

But suppose you want to reduce the boilerplate in any case.  I'd create generators local to the dimension classes which configure themselves on a fact table:

```
class Store(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'store'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(50), nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def add_dimension(cls, target):
        target.store_id = Column('store_id', Integer, ForeignKey('store.id'), primary_key=True)
        target.store = relation(cls)
```

in which case usage would be like:

```
class FactOne(Base):
    ...

Store.add_dimension(FactOne)
```

But, there's a problem with that.  Assuming the dimension columns you're adding are primary key columns, the mapper configuration is going to fail since a class needs to have its primary keys set up before the mapping is set up.   So assuming we're using declarative (which you'll see below has a nice effect), to make this approach work we'd have to use the `instrument_declarative()` function instead of the standard metaclass:

```
meta = MetaData()
registry = {}
def register_cls(*cls):
    for c in cls:
        instrument_declarative(c, registry, meta)
```

So then we'd do something along the lines of:

```
class Store(object):
    # ...

class FactOne(object):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_fact_one'

Store.add_dimension(FactOne)

register_cls(Store, FactOne)
```

If you actually have a good reason for custom join conditions, as long as there's some pattern to how those conditions are created, you can generate that with your `add_dimension()`:

```
class Store(object):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def add_dimension(cls, target):
        target.store_id = Column('store_id', Integer, ForeignKey('store.id'), primary_key=True)
        target.store = relation(cls, primaryjoin=target.store_id==cls.id)
```

But the final cool thing if you're on 2.6, is to turn `add_dimension` into a class decorator.  Here's an example with everything cleaned up:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import instrument_declarative
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

class BaseMeta(type):
    classes = set()
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_):
        klass = type.__init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_)
        if 'metadata' not in dict_:
            BaseMeta.classes.add(cls)
        return klass

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = BaseMeta
    metadata = MetaData()
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        for k in kw:
            setattr(self, k, kw[k])

    @classmethod
    def configure(cls, *klasses):
        registry = {}
        for c in BaseMeta.classes:
            instrument_declarative(c, registry, cls.metadata)

class Store(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'store'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(50), nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def dimension(cls, target):
        target.store_id = Column('store_id', Integer, ForeignKey('store.id'), primary_key=True)
        target.store = relation(cls)
        return target

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(50), nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def dimension(cls, target):
        target.product_id = Column('product_id', Integer, ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True)
        target.product = relation(cls)
        return target

@Store.dimension
@Product.dimension
class FactOne(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_fact_one'

    units_sold = Column('units_sold', Integer, nullable=False)

@Store.dimension
@Product.dimension
class FactTwo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_fact_two'

    units_sold = Column('units_sold', Integer, nullable=False)

Base.configure()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    sess = sessionmaker(engine)()

    sess.add(FactOne(store=Store(name='s1'), product=Product(name='p1'), units_sold=27))
    sess.commit()
```

Comment: Very nice design - beautiful!

Comment: Inspired by this, I finally figured out how to pass configuration to declared_attr, so that libraries can be made aware of host application models: https://gist.github.com/miohtama/844cc78bcf1d317e31ca

Comment: This looks very elegant, but it's now 10 years later, I'm using python 3.6, and it doesn't work for me. I changed the init function of BaseMeta to have `super().__init__(classname, bases, dict_)` to make it compatible with python 3.6, but I'm obviously missing something because I get the error:
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join from scenario; please use select_from() to establish the left entity/selectable of this join